# Is it possible to repair label data in Neo4j?

Tags: database, neo4j

At some point, based on the logs, my Neo4j server got stopped up and was behaving irrationally until I restarted it. I don't have logs showing what caused the issue, but the shutdown sequence dumped several exceptions into the logs, mainly:

```
2015-01-29 22:10:04.204+0000 INFO  [API] Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
...
22:10:20.911 [Thread-13] WARN  o.e.j.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool - qtp313783031{STOPPING,2<=1<=20,i=0,q=0} Couldn't stop Thread[qtp313783031-22088,5,main]
2015-01-29 22:10:20.923+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
2015-01-29 22:10:20.936+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Exception when stopping org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@68698d61 Failed to flush file channel /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Failed to flush file channel /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/neostore.propertystore.db
... stack dump of exception ...
```

During the three day time period before this restart, some nodes and relationships were created that are able to be found in the system but don't have a proper or full label attached to them. See the below queries for an example of the enigma.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (b:Book {book_id: 25937}) return b;
+---+
| b |
+---+
+---+
0 row
105 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (b {book_id: 25937}) return b;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| b                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[97574]{book_id:25937,title:"Writing an autobiography"} |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row
189 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (b {book_id: 25937}) return id(b), labels(b);
+----------------------+
| id(b) | labels(b)    |
+----------------------+
| 97574 | ["Book"]     |
+----------------------+
1 row
165 ms
```

Even if I then explicitly add the label and query for :Book again, it still doesn't return.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (b {book_id: 25937}) set b :Book return b;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| b                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[97574]{book_id:25937,title:"Writing an autobiography"} |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row
143 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (b:Book {book_id: 25937}) return b;
+---+
| b |
+---+
+---+
0 row
48 ms
```

Also not helpful is dropping and recreating the index(es) I have on these nodes.

The fact that these labels aren't functioning properly has caused my code to begin creating second, "duplicate" (exactly the same except with working labels) nodes do to my on-demand architecture.

I'm starting to believe these nodes are never going to work. Before I dive into reproducing ALL the nodes and relationships created during that three day time span, is it possible to repair what's existing?

-- EDIT --

It seems that dropping and recreating the index DOES solve this problem. I was testing immediately after dropping and immediately after recreating, forgetting that the indexes may take time to build. The system was still misbehaving while operating with NO index, so I thought it wasn't working at all.

TL/DR: Try creating an index on the broken nodes.

Comment: I was noticing that the behavior seemed to be gradually getting better, so I wiped all the indexes, waited an hour, then recreated them. This appears to have resolved the issue, despite my earlier findings. The actual recreation of the index seems to have fixed things, not the dropping of the index or working without one.